# I can't delete bad piggies off Galaxy S4

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, uninstallation

I installed the game thinking I'd play it, but I changed my mind. Anyway, that's not too important. I clicked uninstall, and it does say it uninstalled it, but in the application manager, it is still taking up 108 MB, though listed as "Not installed."

If I go to the play store, and try to get the game again, it installs instantly, proving to me that the app is still somewhere on the phone (I don't have 100 MBps internet) How do I get rid of the app completely?

If it's important, I use Android Lollipop 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple. All I had to do was click on the app in the application manager, and press the menu button.  I got an option saying "Uninstall for all users" That's all I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root? I don't know, so I will just say both ways, with and without root.

--With root

Get a Root File Explorer (I recommend ES File Explorer), open the menu, scroll down to the root option and turn in on. Then navigate to /data/app and delete the app file. The file name should be the apps package name. That would be `com.rovio.BadPiggies.apk`. Delete that. I can't remember how Lollipop installs apps, so if /data/app is full of directories, then just delete the directory named `com.rovio.BadPiggies`.

--Without root

You need a computer for this. Download ADB (I'll give you a link) to your computer. `cd` to where ADB was downloaded to. Plug your phone into the computer. Open up a terminal (or CMD if your on Windows). Run `adb devices`. It should list your devices serial number, and it's status. Allow the computer to use ADB. The prompt will be on your phone. 
Run `adb shell`, then run the following commands in order:

```
cd /data/app
ls
```

If ls's output was a bunch of files ending in `.apk` then run `rm com.rovio.BadPiggies.apk`, and if it wasn't, then run `rm com.rovio.BadPiggies`.

Hope this helps